# can you help me with diffence between next and nextline?

Tags: java

I have a LinkedList class in Java, and I need to add to head and add to tail methods with head reference. Everything works fine with integers, but when I try to add String with nextLine() from the Scanner, it adds space as first input. Everything works fine if I input String with next(). Is there some big difference between next and nextLine methods except basic one?

Comment: post your complete code

Answer (score 0):

next() is for reading one word, nextLine() reads whole line.